# YouCompleteMe (ycm), Failed to build regex module

Tags: python-3.x, vim, vim-plugin, anaconda3, youcompleteme

I am trying to install the ycmd plugin for vim (after having ran `git submodule update --init --recursive`) and I am running into: `Failed to build regex module`.

After running `./install.py` in the "YouCompleteMe" folder, here are the upstream lines that lead to the stated error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so
[100%] Built target ycm_core
running build
running build_py
creating /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build
creating /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/regex
copying regex_3/__init__.py -> /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/regex
copying regex_3/regex.py -> /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/regex
copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/regex
copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/regex
running build_ext
building 'regex._regex' extension
creating /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3
creating /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3
gcc -pthread -B /home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o
gcc -pthread -B /home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c regex_3/_regex_unicode.c -o /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex_unicode.o
gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex_unicode.o -o /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/regex/_regex.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/home/users/jeremy/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/home/users/jeremy/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Failed to build regex module.
```

It seems like the /anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld executable is not compatible with the YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/regex-build/3/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o file.

Does someone have an idea of what's going on or what I could try out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem from [someone hitting the same kind of issue while trying to compile PyTorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16683) :

"The whole problem lies in the fact that Anaconda distribution comes with its own ld linker that is located in /opt/anaconda/compiler_compat/ and it overshadows system ld residing at /usr/bin.
To fix my error I ran python setup.py clean and then I temporarily renamed Anaconda's ld linker to ld-old to make it invisible during PyTorch installation. Removing -B option from the installation stage could fix it too."

So renaming my anaconda ld linker for the ycm compilation fixed my issue. (I renamed it back afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) to do code complement, it works so good and is easy to use.

i tried to build YCM so many times several years before, and in the end, i gave up.

Comment: Ok good to know. How many languages does this vim plugin support ? I actually script almost only in python and bash. Also is this as powerful as ycmd ? For example I think there is some nice function jumping in ycmd.

Comment: it supports both python and bash, and is easy to use. just have a try :) 
this might be helpful: https://www.vimfromscratch.com/articles/vim-for-python/